# TikZ not computing intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I'm trying to make two lines intersect using the `(intersection cs: first line={}, second line={})` syntax. However, compilation of the following example doesn't do what I want:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} 
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate (S) at (-5 ,0);
      \coordinate (M'1) at (0,4.5);
      \coordinate (M2) at (0,3);
      \def\angleM{10}

      \draw[color=Red, thick] (M'1) -- (intersection cs: first line={(M'1)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(-5,-5) -- (5,5)}) circle (2pt) -- (S); % (S) -> (M'1)
      \draw[color=Red, thick] (M2) -- (intersection cs: first line={(M2) --++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(45:-4) -- (45:4)}) circle (2pt) -- (S); % (S) -> (M2)

      \draw (S) node[ellipse, fill=white, minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2mm,draw]{$(S)$};
      \begin{scope}[thick]
         \draw[densely dashed] (M'1) ++(1,0) -- ++(-2,0) node[left]{$M'_1$};
         \draw (M2) ++(1,0) -- ++(-2,0) node[left]{$M_2$};
      \end{scope}
      \fill[pattern=north east lines] (M'1) ++(1,0) rectangle ++(-2,0.2);
      \fill[pattern=north east lines] (M2) ++(1,0) rectangle ++(-2,0.2);
      \draw[very thick] (45:-2) -- (45:2);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This code yields this:
[image: compilation-result]

Whereas I want the red lines to intersect with the black line in the center. Is there something I'm doing wrong? The PGF/TikZ manual doesn't provide any example of the intersection syntax with relative paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't leave blank spaces in the specification of the lines in the `intersection` coordinate system: instead of

```
\draw[color=Red, thick] (M'1) -- (intersection cs: first line={(M'1)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(-5,-5) -- (5,5)}) circle (2pt) -- (S); % (S) -> (M'1)
\draw[color=Red, thick] (M2) -- (intersection cs: first line={(M2) --++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(45:-4) -- (45:4)}) circle (2pt) -- (S); % (S) -> (M2)
```

you should use

```
\draw[color=Red, thick] (M'1) -- (intersection cs: first line={(M'1)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(-5,-5)--(5,5)}) circle (2pt) -- (S); % (S) -> (M'1)
\draw[color=Red, thick] (M2) -- (intersection cs: first line={(M2) --++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(45:-4)--(45:4)}) circle (2pt) -- (S); % (S) -> (M2)
```

(to make the explanation more clear, you had `second line={(-5,-5) -- (5,5)}` with spaces on both sides of the `--` and it should be `second line={(-5,-5)--(5,5)})` with no spaces; similar remark for the other `\draw`.

[image]

The code:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} 
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate (S) at (-5 ,0);
      \coordinate (M'1) at (0,4.5);
      \coordinate (M2) at (0,3);
      \def\angleM{10}

      \draw[color=Red, thick] (M'1) -- (intersection cs: first line={(M'1)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(-5,-5)--(5,5)}) circle (2pt) -- (S); % (S) -> (M'1)
      \draw[color=Red, thick] (M2) -- (intersection cs: first line={(M2) --++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(45:-4)--(45:4)}) circle (2pt) -- (S); % (S) -> (M2)

      \draw (S) node[ellipse, fill=white, minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2mm,draw]{$(S)$};
      \begin{scope}[thick]
         \draw[densely dashed] (M'1) ++(1,0) -- ++(-2,0) node[left]{$M'_1$};
         \draw (M2) ++(1,0) -- ++(-2,0) node[left]{$M_2$};
      \end{scope}
      \fill[pattern=north east lines] (M'1) ++(1,0) rectangle ++(-2,0.2);
      \fill[pattern=north east lines] (M2) ++(1,0) rectangle ++(-2,0.2);
      \draw[very thick] (45:-2) -- (45:2);
      \coordinate (L) at  ( $ (80 :-8) + (0,4.5) $ );
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In fact, you can leave a blank space before the `--` but not after it! Perhaps this could be considered a bug?

Comment: Thank you. How could I know when I can and cannot add spaces? I used them for visibility purpose, and didn't even suspect them from making the compilation fail at finding the intersection.

Comment: @LaX in normal circumstances (a simple `to` path, for example) you can leave spaces, but in this case, they are not allowed (I don't really know if this is a design choice, since they are allowed before, but not after the `--`). Another case in which this restriction applies is when using the `angle` pic in which you cannot use spaces, so you have to use {angle = A--B--C} and not `{angle = A -- B -- C}`.