# Why do these two TikZ instructions produce different results?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I'm playing around with intersections to draw an illustration for a lecture about optics. However, I'm having a few issues as the following example shows:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} 
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate (M2) at (0,3);
      \def\angleM{10}
% >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      \draw[color=Red, thick] (M2) --  (intersection cs: first line={(M2)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(45:-4)--(45:4)}) circle (2pt);
      \draw[color=Red, thick] (intersection cs: first line={(M2)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(45:-4)--(45:4)}) circle (2pt) -- (M2);
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      \draw[thick] (M2) ++(1,0) -- ++(-2,0) node[left]{$M_2$};
      \fill[pattern=north east lines] (M2) ++(1,0) rectangle ++(-2,0.2);
      \draw[very thick] (45:-2) -- (45:2);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In this example, the two lines between `% >>>>>…` and `% <<<<…` should draw the same lines, but don't as you can see here:

[image: intersection]

While the instructions are almost the same (only the draw direction differs), the lines don't overlap as they should. What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: intersection library is very sensitive to rounding errors, that's the problem.

Comment: @yo' Is there anything I could use instead?

Comment: compute the points manually? ... I know it sucks. Maybe someone knows what to do better. I unfrotunately do not.

Comment: @yo' but I want to do the draw multiple times with different parameters and many intersections, so I'll need to find a flexible solution. (This is the experiment I'm drawing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson–Morley_experiment)

Comment: @LaX as a workaround, you can use the `intersections` library `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}` and then do
`\path[name path=line1] (M2)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)
[name path=line2] (45:-4)--(45:4); 
\draw[Red,thick,name intersections={of=line1 and line2}] (intersection-1) -- (M2);` it's a bit longer than using the `intersection cs`, but you won't be depending on rounding problems.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That's actually an excellent solution, as all my intersecting lines are already existing paths (mirrors). However, I now have to declare these paths before the intersection, whereas I like to have the mirrors drawn on top of the beams. Is there a kind of layer library I could use for that?

Comment: @LaX there's the `background` library exactly for this. Have a look at the PGF manual, Section **109 Layered Graphics**.

Comment: For optical illustrations and setups you might want to have a look at the [pst-optexp](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-optexp) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a rounding problem. This problem and the one discussed in [TikZ not computing intersection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229297/3954) suggest that there are some problems with the intersection coordinate system (in fact, the PGF manual doesn't mention it and only presents an example of its use).

Anyway, as a workaround, you could load the `intersections` library and then do

```
\path
  [name path=line1] (M2) -- ++(90 - \angleM:-8) 
  [name path=line2] (45:-4) -- (45:4); 
\draw[Red,thick,name intersections={of=line1 and line2}] 
  (intersection-1) circle (2pt) -- (M2);
```

this is just a bit longer than using the `intersection cs`, but you won't be troubled by different results resulting from rounding problems. A complete example showing both approaches side-by-side:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} 
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
      \coordinate (M2) at (0,3);
      \def\angleM{10}
% >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      \draw[color=Red, thick] (M2) --  (intersection cs: first line={(M2)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(45:-4)--(45:4)}) circle (2pt);
      \draw[color=Red, thick] (intersection cs: first line={(M2)--++(90 - \angleM:-8)}, second line={(45:-4)--(45:4)}) circle (2pt) -- (M2);
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      \draw[thick] (M2) ++(1,0) -- ++(-2,0) node[left]{$M_2$};
      \fill[pattern=north east lines] (M2) ++(1,0) rectangle ++(-2,0.2);
      \draw[very thick] (45:-2) -- (45:2);
   \end{tikzpicture}\qquad
%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
      \coordinate (M2) at (0,3);
      \def\angleM{10}

      \path
        [name path=line1] (M2) -- ++(90 - \angleM:-8) 
        [name path=line2] (45:-4) -- (45:4); 
      \draw[Red,thick,name intersections={of=line1 and line2}] 
        (intersection-1) circle (2pt) -- (M2);

      \draw[thick] (M2) ++(1,0) -- ++(-2,0) node[left]{$M_2$};
      \fill[pattern=north east lines] (M2) ++(1,0) rectangle ++(-2,0.2);
      \draw[very thick] (45:-2) -- (45:2);
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]